# tx:annotation-driven not working

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hello friend i'm developing spring(4.0.3) and hibernate(4.3.6) based application. 
I'm facing following error when I saved any object in session factory:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
20:38:59,881 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
```

And following is the entry which I have used in my application-context.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryAthena" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

On more thing I'd like to bring here if I used any value in transaction-manager attribute instead actual transactionManager for bean reference then its not throwing error.
So i think its not taking reference bean value.
Please help me!!

Comment: Have you written session.beginTransaction()?
You have to call 

   Session session=getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
   Transaction trans=session.beginTransaction();
  Please check once.

Comment: I'm using spring transaction manager so i don't thing so that i need to write session.beginTransaction().It will handle automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look in this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) but follows an example using xml.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryAthena" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <!-- the transactional advice (what happens; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with get are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name=""/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

But nowadays I have been seeing the spring community using declarative transactions with annotations. Like the example below:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
        // do something
    }

    // these settings have precedence for this method
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `@EnableTransactionManagement` at the top of your class:

```
@Component
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Abc{

}
```